# Visual Studio Code чтобы при нажатием мышки на модуль или функцию в другой вкладке открывался исходный код этого модуля/функции

Tags: visual-studio-code

В `PhpStorm` или в `Netbeans` при нажатием мышки на модуль или функцию в другой вкладке открывается исходный код этого модуля/функции.

В `Visual Studio Code` такого функционала нет, а он очень нужен. Существует ли способ реализовать такой функционал?

P.S. Насколько мне известно, для каждого языка свой вариант реализации этого. Мне нужно для `php`.

Comment: Как минимум нужно установить расширение, нужное для поддержки PHP (обычно vscode сам предлагает). После этого должен заработать переход на модуль или функцию через их имя при клике с зажатым Ctrl.

Comment: @ insolor, оказалось все проще, чем я думал. Действительно, установил 2 рекомендуемых расширения: ```PHP Debug``` и ```PHP Intelephense``` и нужный функционал появился.